# Primary monitor not saving

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors

I want my primary monitor to be my AOC but this is not saved whenever I shut down my computer. The correct monitor is set as primary in monitors.xml
[image: monitors.xml]
This seems to make no difference and my BenQ is still set as primary in my Xserver settings
[image: xsettings]
I have tried most of the other similar questions on here but none of them have helped.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue once with getting the set screen resolution to stick between reboots.
I had to create a config file in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.
Please correct me if I'm wrong, but IIRC the default behaviour (At least on my system in question) of the X-server is to autoconfigure itself on every boot, and basicly ignoring any config files unless it is explicitly told to read them.

Comment: yeah I've already created that file and it doesn't seem to change anything